# Spawn ftp command does not work on Tcl expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I have tried so many variations of code to start the ftp command on tcl, but none of them work, from examples on the internet, here are the ones I have tried:

```
spawn ftp ftp.uu.net  Error: couldn't execute "ftp": no such file or directory
spawn ftp.uu.net
spawn ftp
expect spawn ftp ftp.uu.net
exec spawn ftp.uu.net
```

I cant seem to find a solution to make ftp work on tcl expect any where on any website.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first thing I would you check is your path. **

My guess is that ftp is not in your path, or tcl is not getting the path from your system.  You can find out what tcl ( Expect ) has as the path with :

> puts "$env(PATH)"

It probably doesn't matter but what is your OS?

> tclsh
>
> % package require Expect
>   % spawn sftp ftp.uuu.net

Comment: I am using centOS and it is in my path. I added it to the path (following steps from a previous post). It still does not recognise the command

Comment: What happens if you say: spawn /sbin/ftp ftp.uu.net ? ( replace /sbin/ with the location of ftp i.e )

Comment: No Such file or directory. Extrapolating from what you suggested, i tried doing "spawn /path/to/ftp/ user@host" (the path is from the env(path) command) and I get access denied.

Comment: spawn is only a valid command in Expect.  ftp user@host is what you would try.  And isn't mostly 'sftp' these days?

Comment: sftp does work, I guess they disabled the ftp feature, even though I added it to the path